# Потеряно соединение с сервером MySQL во время выполнения запроса

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, mysqlconnector

при выполнении моей программы у меня удается соединиться с сервером MySQL, но при первом же запросе у меня выходит ошибка потери соединения во время запроса, в интернете говорят, что дело в глобальных переменных сервера или скорости интернета (в частности на официальном сайте такую информацию добыл), но переменные стоят с вполне адекватными значениями, а скорость интернета нормальная (тем более, что я подключаюсь на localhost).

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>


#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    MYSQL *mysql;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *res;

    std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string user = "root";
    std::string passwd = "password";
    std::string db = "test";
    int port = 3306;

    mysql_init(mysql);

    mysql_real_connect(mysql, host.c_str(), user.c_str(), passwd.c_str(), db.c_str(), port, NULL, 0);
    std::cout << mysql_error(mysql) << std::endl;

    mysql_set_character_set(mysql, "utf8");

    mysql_query(mysql, "SELECT * FROM users");
    
    if(res = mysql_store_result(mysql)){
        while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res)){
            for(int i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++){
                std::cout << row[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << mysql_error(mysql) << std::endl;
    }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(mysql);
}
```

Comment: У вас в первой же строке сразу две ошибки - использование неинициализированного указателя `mysql` и игнорирование значения, возвращаемого `mysql_init`.

Comment: "mysql_init : If mysql is a NULL pointer, the function allocates, initializes, and returns a new object." - вы **не** передали нулевой указатель , а на самом деле случайное значение памяти. А также новый указатель, полученный от функции никуда не сохранили. так будет правильнее : `mysql = mysql_init ( NULL ) ;` читайте доку : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-init.html